# How to get the length of an mp4 video inside a node?

Tags: python, node-editor

Work with python in blender 2.8 , i try to find a command for get the lenght of an video inside at image node.

```
ob = bpy.context.active_object
nodes = ob.active_material.node_tree.nodes

    for n in nodes:
        if n.name == "Image Texture":
            if n.image:
                video = n.image
                ##print(video.lenght)##
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of a video file is stored in the [`frame_duration`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.frame_duration) property.

```
num_frames = n.image.frame_duration
```

If you wanted duration in time, divide the frames by the `fps` property.

```
seconds = num_frames / n.image.fps
```

Comment: Ty sambler, That's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think your script need to check if `fn.lower().endswith('.mp4')`

Comment: Ty Alexa, i have if statement now